# How long should Azure Kinect timeouts be?

Tags: azurekinect

So I have a working version of the Kinect working in its own thread and I want the application to to run at 60 fps (despite the cameras running at 30, which is fine). Getting the frame and body tracking data is working perfectly with a wait time of

```
(1.f/60.f)*1000.f
```

milliseconds, but I have a feeling that calling **k4a_device_get_capture**, **k4abt_tracker_enqueue_capture**, and **k4abt_tracker_pop_result** at this wait length cause spill over into the subsequent frames (possibly up to 3).

Am I wrong on this? Should I divide this all further by 3? Or am I just over thinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in the SDK pipeline will cause k4a_device_get_capture to return a failure, so your timeout should be a reflection how slow the host PC can become before failing, or how many dropped frames you can tolerate. You could use an infinite timeout and call k4a_device_stop_cameras() to unblock the thread calling k4a_device_get_capture.

Comment: Thanks, this actually cleared up what I was trying to figure out. I can see how a slower machine (like a laptop) could make use of infinite to get a good read out in time.